# Prove $\log u > \frac{u - 1}{u}$ for $u > 1$

Tags: derivatives, logarithms, taylor-expansion

How to prove that for $u > 1$ $$\log u > \frac{u - 1}{u}$$ without using integrals? I think I'm supposed to use derivatives or Taylor's theorem, as the exercise comes from a lecture about these subjects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just derivate 
$$
f'(u)=\left(\log u - \frac{u - 1}{u}\right)'=\frac1u-\frac1{u^2}=\frac{u-1}{u^2}>0, \quad u>1,
$$ and use the fact that $f(1)=0$ to conclude.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Oh my God, that's been so easy that I'm really embarassed. Thank you. Yes, I think I can take it from here. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just consider $f(x)=x\log x-x+1$ in $(1,\infty)$
and find it's derivative. $$f'(x)=\log x \gt0$$ Thus $f$ is strictly increasing in $(1,\infty)$, so $f(1)=0\lt f(x)=x\log x-x+1$, $\forall x \in (1,\infty)$ so 
$$x\log x-x+1\gt0\\ \log x\gt \frac{x-1}{x}$$
and you have the desired inequality.